# Connected circles which sum of any two of them which are adjacent is a triangle numbers

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Arrange numbers 1 to 36 to the small circles and ovals, with rules:

- sum of any two of them which are adjacent is a [triangle numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).
- The first 12 Triangle numbers are 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66
- Some numbers are already there as guide.
- There is only 1 unique solution.

<sub>The puzzle is inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57441/another-loop-of-integers-with-consecutive-terms-adding-to-a-square)</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [image: Solution Image]

- First circle corresponds to the "top" circle in the question image
- Second circle corresponds to the "right" circle in the question image
- Third circle corresponds to the "bottom" circle in the question image
- Red highlighted nodes are the ones connected to the other circles (should hopefully be obvious which way)
- Note that the "orientation" of the circles should be the same as in the question image (i.e., no reflecting necessary)